# How to remove value of the class in an existing code (wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, attributes

I need to remove 'mylogin' that is inside the class.
I tried the folloing code but it doesn't remove 'mylogin'.
Would you please let me know how to remove it?
Existing code:

```
<div class="elementor-column elementor-element-84c7af1 mylogin" data-id="84c7af1" 
data-element_type="column" id="my-checkout">
```

I tried:

```
<?php
 echo '<script>';
 echo 'function myFunction() { var element = document.getElementById("my-checkout"); ';
 echo 'element.classList.remove("mylogin");}'; 
 echo '</script>';
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you do this in PHP?  Add it to one of your existing JS files, but wrap it in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', {})` first.

Comment: Hi, I need to add if condition (if url contains 'my-pay', remove 'mylogin' in the class). I'm ad newbie, very clumsy... PHP is a little bit easier than jQuery to me, so I did it in PHP. And... I have no idea how to solve it using jQuery.. Thanks prieber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to execute the JS function you've created. Wrapping in brackets and then executing using the brackets after is how it will be fired.

e.g.

```js
function(){ alert("I won't do anything until requested"); }

(function(){ alert("I get fired immediately"); })();
```

Below will add the JS block IF the current url/slug contains `my-pay`.

```php
$removeMyLoginJs = <<<EOD
<script>
    (function myFunction() {
        var element = document.getElementById("my-checkout");
        element.classList.remove("mylogin");
    })();
</script>
EOD;

global $wp;
$currentSlug = add_query_arg([], $wp->request);

if(strpos($currentSlug, "my-pay") !== false){
    echo $removeMyLoginJs;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay: thnak you a lot for your kind hlep : ). I copy and pasted the code in php of the checkout page, but it still shows 'mylogin'. If possible, would you please let me know what else I can try?

Comment: Hi Jay: Oh, Wow, Thank you a lot for your help. I put your code before the div code creates, my bad. Thanks again Jay, you were a big help, have a nice weekend : )